# Issue with configuring Oracle 21 XE DB after removing Oracle 18 XE DB

Tags: oracle

I had installed Oracle 18 XE DB in my linux machine. Now I have uninstalled it and installed Oracle 21 XE DB in the same machine. The issue is when I run the below command to configure Oracle 21XE DB, I get a message : **There is an Oracle Database instance XE already configured in the server.**

Command to configure - /etc/init.d/oracle-xe-21c configure

Comment: Sounds to me like when you un-installed 18, you left its database in place.   "Install" and "uninstall" deals with the software, not the database.

Comment: it is in /etc/oratab,there is most probably a line about your old database. Delete it

Answer (score 0):

There was an entry for Oracle 18 in `/etc/oratab`.

After deleting the entry, I was able to setup Oracle 21 successfully.